# base64 decode string and encode all special characters lost

Tags: android, json, base64

I have a Java class which I convert to string using GSON. Post this the string is base64 encoded (for some reason, lets not go there :) ) When I decode it back I lose all { and " " characters in json.

For example: {"name":"ABC"} decoded and encoded back becomes nameABC

I want to get my old data back i.e I want {"name:"ABC"} back

```
String json = "{\"name\":\"ABC\"}";
byte en[] = android.util.Base64.decode(json,Base64.NO_WRAP);
String st = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(en,Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Something as simple as above, content is lost

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `Base64` has set 64 characters that can converted to binary and vice versa, characters like { and " is not in the 64 set of characters check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Try using `URLDecoder` with `UTF-8` or any other encoding method which support UTF-8

Comment: Tried, doesn't work :( Tried others like URL_SAFE etc etc too

Comment: Output comes as nameABA= for Base64.DEFAULT

Comment: yeah just don't use Base64